# Forcing driving direction using edited OSM shapefile and pgRouting

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, network, graph

I need to edit a shapefile from OSM in QGIS. I want to use pgRouting to find a route, where it uses a forced driving direction. The algorithm may use the same edge however to calculate the route further. So, it has to use the forced driving direction, but it may use the same edge in the opposite direction, (unless an edge is really one-way).

Do I just add another column, and if so, how do I go about that?

---

More details about the use case:

Working with waste collection. Meaning the bins are on one side of the road. The truck has a loading arm on the right side. Meaning we have to drive through the street in the right way to load. After that we may use the road to transit to another part... So, in order to load the bins the road has to temporary one way but after that may be used in the opposite direction. From historical data we know where the bins are.

Comment: Sounds like an optimization problem. That's much harder to solve than ordinary routing.

Comment: You can do such optimization (curb-side) with our RW Net 4 product (www.routeware.dk), just in case pgRouting can not handle it.